# Authentication Required - Problems Establishing AIM OSCAR Session using Python

Tags: python, json, aim

I'm writing a simple python script that will interface with the AIM servers using the [OSCAR protocol](http://dev.aol.com/aim/oscar/). It includes a somewhat complex handshake protocol. You essentially have to send a GET request to a specific URL, receive XML or JSON encoded reply, extract a special session token and secret key, then generate a response using the token and the key.

I tried to follow [these steps](http://dev.aol.com/aim/oscar/#AUTH) to a tee, but the process fails in the last one. Here is my code:

```
class simpleOSCAR:
  def __init__(self, username, password):
    self.username = username
    self.password = password

    self.open_aim_key = 'whatever'
    self.client_name = 'blah blah blah'
    self.client_version = 'yadda yadda yadda'


  def authenticate(self):

    # STEP 1
    url = 'https://api.screenname.aol.com/auth/clientLogin?f=json'
        data = urllib.urlencode( [
                 ('k', self.open_aim_key), 
                 ('s', self.username),
                 ('pwd', self.password), 
                 ('clientVersion', self.client_version),
                 ('clientName', self.client_name)]
                )

    response = urllib2.urlopen(url, data)
    json_response = simplejson.loads(urllib.unquote(response.read()))

    session_secret = json_response['response']['data']['sessionSecret']
    host_time = json_response['response']['data']['hostTime']
    self.token = json_response['response']['data']['token']['a']

    # STEP 2
    self.session_key = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(self.password, session_secret, sha256).digest())

    #STEP 3
    uri = "http://api.oscar.aol.com/aim/startOSCARSession?"

    data = urllib.urlencode([   
                    ('a', self.token),  
                    ('clientName', self.client_name),
                    ('clientVersion', self.client_version),
                    ('f', 'json'),
                    ('k', self.open_aim_key), 
                    ('ts', host_time), 
                                    ]
                )
    urldata = uri+data
    hashdata = "GET&" + urllib.quote("http://api.oscar.aol.com/aim/startOSCARSession?") + data

    digest = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(self.session_key, hashdata, sha256).digest())

    urldata =  urldata + "&sig_sha256=" + digest

    print urldata + "\n"

    response = urllib2.urlopen(urldata)
    json_response = urllib.unquote(response.read())

    print json_response

if __name__ == '__main__':
so = simpleOSCAR("aimscreenname", "somepassword")
so.authenticate()
```

I get the following response from the server:

```
{ "response" : {
                 "statusCode":401, 
                 "statusText":"Authentication Required. statusDetailCode 1014",
                 "statusDetailCode":1014, 
                 "data":{
                           "ts":1235878395
                         }
               }
}
```

I tried troubleshooting it in various ways, but the URL's I generate look the same as the ones shown in the [signon flow example](http://dev.aol.com/aim/oscar/#SIGNON). And yet, it fails.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? Am I hashing the values wrong? Am I encoding something improperly? Is my session timing out?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Comment: Nah, never figured it out. I got bored and sort of moved on to other stuff.

Comment: I actually figured it out. Basically, I just looked at the libpurple source code and debugged my code with that...

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Twisted's OSCAR support](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/trunk/twisted/words/protocols/oscar.py) instead of writing your own?  It hasn't seen a lot of maintenance, but I believe it works.

Answer (score 0):

URI Encode your digest?

-moxford

Comment: Tried that and it didn't work. Plus the examples in the docs explicitly show you not to URI encode it.

Good try though. Thanks!